# How would you access derived methods using a base pointer ?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have seen several posts on this topic, but did not find the kind of solution I am looking for. So sorry at the outset for yet another duplicate. But I want to know what you experts will do faced with a situation as given below ?

```
class Vehicle // A base class
{
    public:
        static Vehicle* CreateInstance(const int createWhat)
        {
            switch(createWhat)
            {
                case 1:
                    return new Segway();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    return new Car();
                    break;
            }            
        }
};
```

Now I have a couple of derived classes ..

```
class Segway : public Vehicle   // Segway is a vehicle
{
};

class Sensor
class FuelConsumptionInfo;
class Car : public Vehicle      // Car is a vehicle
{
    public:
        std::list<Sensor>& GetSensorList()
        { 
            return m_pListOfSensors;
        }
        bool CompareThisCarAgainstOthers(std::list<Vehicle*>& vehicles) const
        {
            bool isMostEfficientCar = false;
            std::list<Vehicle*>::iterator iterVal = vehicles.begin();
            while(iterVal != vehicles.end())
            {
                // 1. Get the list of sensors of this car and compare against the sensors of this car ... 
                // 2. Get the fuel consumption information and compare against the fuel efficiency of this car ...
            }
            return isMostEfficientCar;
        }

    private:
        std::list<Sensor*> m_pListOfSensors;
        FuelConsumptionInfo* m_FuelEfficiency;
};
```

And finally I have my favourite car and a set of other cars, and I want to compare my car against them.

```
int main()
{
    std::list<Vehicle*> listOfOtherCars;
    Vehicle* pMyFavCar = Vehicle::CreateInstance(2);
    listOfOtherCars.push_back(Vehicle::CreateInstance(2));
    listOfOtherCars.push_back(Vehicle::CreateInstance(2));
    listOfOtherCars.push_back(Vehicle::CreateInstance(2));
    listOfOtherCars.push_back(Vehicle::CreateInstance(2));

    // How can I invoke the CompareThisCarAgainstOthers without:
    // 1. Introducing any base class empty functions .. 
    // 2. Without using static/dynamic casting to convert the base pointer to a derived class pointer ...     
}
```

As already mentioned in the comments, I want to invoke the *CampareThisCarAgainstOthers*, but I do not want to cast the base class pointer, nor do I want to introduce any virtual functions in the base class which I think defies the whole logic of having a base class. Even introducing empty virtual base functions will not help because *GetSensorList* returns a reference to the list.

I will be very thankful to your answers.

Comment: If you want to play with `Car`s, then use `std::list<Car *>`.  If you want to play with Motorcycles, boats, snowmobiles and bicycles, the use `std::list<Vehicle*>`.  Remember, all you can guarantee from a `std::list<Vehicle *>` are the public methods and members of the `Vehicle` class.  Remember, the list can contain other vehicles than cars.

Comment: Exactly. I also think that this is the only possible way to accomplish this: Maintain a dedicated list of Cars. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: `GetSensorList()` is incorrect, its return type does not match the type of the variable it's returning.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to access a child method using a base pointer is by casting the base pointer to a child pointer.  This has bad side effects <s>(search the internet for "C++ object slicing")</s>.

One issue is that you don't know what kind of child / object the base pointer is pointing to.  You could cast the pointer to a wrong child method. Example: a pointer to a Cruise Ship is passed to a function taking a pointer to vehicle.  What happens when inside the function, the pointer is cast to a `Bicycle` type.  Clearly, not the same vehicle.

All you can safely access with a pointer to a base class is the public methods and members of the base class.  No more, no less.

For example, given a base class of `Car` and some child classes such as `Model_T`, `Tesla`, `Hybrid` and `Mustang`, and a pointer to a `Car` instance, you don't know what kind of car the child is.  A `Model_T` is different than an electric `Tesla`.  A `Mustang` with a gasoline engine is different than a `Hybrid` with both electric and gasoline engines.

If you want to access functionality using a base class pointer, put the functionality into the base class as an abstract function.  The `Car` class could have a method `virtual bool has_electric_engine(void) const = 0;`.  The `Model_T` and `Mustang` would return `false`.

Please don't make virtual equality methods into a base class because the code will be comparing attributes, but you really want to compare types.  In the example, the `Mustang` car does not have all the same attributes as the `Model_T`.  Usually, if you need to compare types, your design is flawed.

Comment: While casting pointers is, indeed,a bad idea, it has nothing to do with slicing. Slicing is about objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Sadly it still does not answer my question. Sorry for not presenting it in the right way. It was immediately voted down for not doing enough research. The intention of the question is to know what would you do if you were to compare two cars, without using casting and implementing car related functions in the base class. I see no other way than really maintaining two different lists. One dedicated for cars and perhaps others for other vehicles.

Comment: The first paragraph is incorrect, another way is to have the method be virtual in the base class.  Also, casting does not have bad side effects so long as you cast to the right type.